# Component Snapping?

Tags: snapping

What are the steps to Component snap?
example: Silo hotkey is SHIFT+~
It allows alignment of face, edge, vertex to be moved to the exact height of a different face, edge or vertex even if the mesh is not combined (joined).
[image: component snapping image]

Comment: Scale to 0 along the axis perpendicular to the faces. E.g. S > Y > 0

Comment: The red arrow is pointing to the unselected face height. The two selected faces need to snap to that height.

Comment: Select the target height face, snap the cursor to it. Scale the other faces to the cursor. [Hotkey . > 3D Cursor]